# UITextView Background Color

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am trying to get white text with a black background or transparent background for the `UITextView` in Xcode 5. There is no slider or setting for this in Xcode, must have been one in previous versions from what I can see in the questions here. but not anymore. I also have seen this

```
UItextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

as a way to fix it. But not sure where to put this as, if its even right.  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can do it programmatically:

```
UITextView *txt = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 60)] autorelease];
[txt setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[txt setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

but you can also accomplish this via the Attribute inspector of the graphic editor setting respectively the properties Color to 'White Color' and Background to 'Clear Color'.

This is the result with a custom background:

[image: UITextView with alpha background and white color text]

Comment: I don't see a picker in the attributes area for background, only text color

Comment: FOUND IT. not sure why i didn't see it this morning.

Comment: That panel has more sections. The text color property is inside the 'Text View' section, the 'Background Color' is in the 'View' section (that contains properties inherited from View class). If you click on the top area of each section, you'll hide such section and you have to click again to reopen it!

Answer (score 2):

You should be write/set any property of your `UITextView`  after initialization

```
_myTextViewName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // set clear backGround color or set as you want
_myTextViewName.textColor  = [UIColor whiteColor]; // set white text color or set as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UItextView *yourTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 ,320, 50)];
yourTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
yourTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubView:yourTextView];
```

Answer (score -1):

For swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Looking for a UITextView - not Field.